# Binding a queue<double> with the PointAndFigure Chart

Tags: c#, charts

I cannot figure out how to bind a `Queue<double>` to a PointAndFigure Chart in C#. I already did:

```
// q is a Queue<double> modified somewhere else
pointAndFigureChart1.DataSource = q;
```

I think I also need to set either `XValueMembers` or `YValueMembers`. The problem is I don't know the name of the *column* because there is NO column in my data source at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my Experience with charts you need to add your queue data to a series and add that series to the chart control. Something like this.

```
this.chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(myQ);
```

Comment: Excellent glad to help!!  Luckily I have an old charting project I did handy!  Also something that I got into once i figured out how to get my data is the tooltip feature which took me a while.  I wanted customized tool tip info and here is how you access your series  values in the tool tip                                                                                       this.chart1.series["series1"].ToolTip = "Time: #AXISLABEL \nValue: #VALY" the #AXISLABEL grabs the x axis label at that point and the #VALY gets the value. It took me a while to find that so I figured I would give it here.